# C++ regular expression from process memory

Tags: c++, regex

I want to extract e-mail addresses from notepad process memory. I open notepad and type e-mail addresses into it. I have a program that scans the entire notepad process memory, but i cannot extract e-mail addresses from notepad memory. There is the code:

```
        while(ptr<=(char*)0x7FFF0000)
    {
        VirtualQueryEx(hProcess,(LPCVOID)ptr,&info,sizeof(info));
        if(info.AllocationProtect!=0x01)
        {
            int bytes_to_read = (int)info.RegionSize;
            std::string buffer;
            DWORD bytes_read;
            buffer.resize(info.RegionSize);
            ReadProcessMemory(hProcess,info.BaseAddress,&buffer[0],bytes_to_read,&bytes_read);
            buffer.resize(bytes_read);
            const std::tr1::regex rx("([\\w-+]+(?:\\.[\\w-+]+)*@(?:[\\w-]+\\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,7})");
            std::tr1::match_results<std::string::const_iterator> res;
            if(std::tr1::regex_search(buffer, res, rx))
            {
                cout << "Found: " << pe32.szExeFile << "\n";
                for ( unsigned int i=0; i<res.size(); ++i)
                {
                cout << res[i] << std::endl ;
                }
                system("pause");
            }
        }
        ptr += info.RegionSize;
```

Comment: Seems innocent enough...

Comment: what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Well... what happens? What do you expect to happen? Where does it "go wrong"?

Comment: the program does not find any email address that i type in notepad.

Comment: Looks lke the regex is not working ok, did you test it well? xyz@gmail.com did this work?

Comment: http://regexr.com?37k0e

Comment: yes, i tested and it works

Comment: Remember strings aren't always stored as you expect in memory, characters might be two bytes for Unicode storage.

Comment: in fact i just checked and notepad _does_ store text in memory as unicode, at 0xAA210 in my case

Comment: use a wstring? also that &buffer[0] thing is pretty suspicious